# Find posts by related taxonomy field

Tags: meta-query

I have "projects" (a custom post type), with many custom fields (created via ACF), one of which relates the project to an "artist" (a custom taxonomy).

Finally, I have "products" that also use the custom taxonomy "artist".

On a product page, I would like to fetch the latest "project" that was related to that same artist.

Here is the code that I believe should work, but it returns an empty array (it should return three projects).

```
$projects = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'artist', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"' . $artist->term_id . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I've double-checked that $artist->term_id returns a correct value: it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're meta querying on serialized data. I mean the `artist` from `'key' => 'artist'` is serialized. That's why your meta query hasn't work. So here is my possible solution-

```
$projects = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'artist', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"%' . $artist->term_id . '%"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

With this wild cards `%` on both side of your `$artist->term_id` will work I think.

Comment: Close enough: in fact the data is stored as an Int, so simply removing the double quotes around the value solved it :)